# Getting org.apache.camel.InvalidPayloadException

Tags: spring-mvc, activemq-classic, apache-camel, jbossfuse

HI I am getting following error when i am using spring+ jboss fuse + Apache active MQ,
I heard there is some type converts if type converters is solution please give me a good sample

My route in camel-context.xml is :

```
<route id="visa-inprogress-trigger" autoStartup="{{visa.inprogress.task.autostart}}">
            <description>Visa In-Progress Trigger</description>
            <from uri="timer://visaInprogressTrigger?period={{visa.document.generation.trigger.interval}}"/>
            <bean ref="visaInProcessTrigger" method="trigger" />
            <to uri="jmsTemplateComponent:visa-inprogress-queue"/>          
        </route>

        <route id="visa-inprogress-handler" autoStartup="{{visa.inprogress.task.autostart}}">
            <description>Visa In-progress Handler</description>
            <from uri="amqComponent:queue:visa-inprogress-queue"/>
            <bean ref="visaInProcessHandler" method="handle" />
        </route>
```

My trigger will returns List> after that I am getting exception like  below

**org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[JmsMessage[JmsMessageID: ID:HMECD000781-58596-1378127658725-3:1:24:1:1]]

Caused by: org.apache.camel.InvalidPayloadException: No body available of type: org.springframework.util.LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap but has value: "phani" of type: java.lang.String on: JmsMessage[JmsMessageID: ID:HMECD000781-58596-1378127658725-3:1:24:1:1]. Caused by: No type converter available to convert from type: java.lang.String to the required type: org.springframework.util.LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap with value "some blah some blah". Exchange[JmsMessage[JmsMessageID: ID:HMECD000781-58596-1378127658725-3:1:24:1:1]]. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException - No type converter available to convert from type: java.lang.String to the required type: org.springframework.util.LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap with value "some blah some blah"]

Caused by: org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException: No type converter available to convert from type: java.lang.String to the required type: org.springframework.util.LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap with value "some blah some blah"

**

Please reply me asap

Comment: That'a a very long stack trace. You might want to shorten it to just the relevant parts. What does the code of your Camel route look like?

Comment: @Jake I updated my question as you asked

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what your `jmsTemplateComponent` does, but the standard JMS/ActiveMQ component can have messages sent to it.

```
<to uri="amqComponent:queue:visa-inprogress-queue"/>
```

Comment: I am able to send object to visa-inprogress-queue, but I am failed to receive from  visa-inprogress-queue

Comment: Take a look at the ActiveMQ statistics through JMX. In the queue stats, see whether the enqueueCount has gone up when you sent the message, and whether the dequeueCount is incremented. The latter will indicate whether the message has been received. Also, add a log statement in the second route immediately after the `from` - this will indicate whether a message has reached the route.